# Not able to store data generated by function into global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store weather data that I am getting from api into global variable but getting undefined instead.
What I am doing wrong?
following is my code.

```
var Data ;

var GetData = function(){

    this.findLocation = function(position)
    {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(2);
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(2);
        this.getWeatherData = function(lat,lon){

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&units=metric&APPID=2048abd4ff09cb4aa1f62dc9a077ba6", false);
            xhr.send();
            var data = xhr.response;
            return this.wData = JSON.parse(data);
        };
        Data = this.getWeatherData(this.latitude,this.longitude);

    };


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.findLocation);

};


GetData();
console.log(Data);
```

Comment: When you down vote please provide comments ,so that they can improve.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code, ANMo...

### Make your code asynchronous

First of all, you should not use synchronous requests to call an external API. See what Mozilla thinks about this practice in its documentation for developers ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)):

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 /
>   SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been
>   deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

You should definitely refactor your code to make it asynchronous. This is how Ajax works...

### Avoid global variables

Using global variables is a terrible idea in JavaScript. You should keep the global scope as clean as possible to avoid unexpected conflicts.

### Use constructor functions properly

In your code, you are trying to use a constructor function but you call it as a basic function. If you want to create an instance from a constructor function, you must use the `new` keyword.